# Large Int Set in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm having the following problem in **sml**:
i want to create a set using the `IntListSet` signature but instead of `int` I want to use `large int`.
Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you,
awaiting for your answer
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ListSetFn` functor.  From the documentation, you will find:

```
functor ListSetFn (ORD_KEY) : ORD_SET
```

This says that `ListSetFn` is a functor that takes a structure satisfying the `ORD_KEY` signature, which you can find in the documentation as:

```
type ord_key
val compare : (ord_key * ord_key) -> order
```

So basically, you need to create a structure that satisfies the `ORD_KEY` signature, such as:

```
structure LargeIntKey : ORD_KEY = 
struct 
  type ord_key = LargeInt.int 
  val compare = LargeInt.compare
end
```

And then you can create a `LargeInt` instance of the `ListSetFn` functor by doing:

```
 structure LargeIntSet = ListSetFn(LargeIntKey)
```